# Creating an anonymous type depending on different conditions and casting it to a class

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-types

I have this problem for sometime now but today I reached the tipping point and I'm asking for your help.

Suppose I have this code:

```
var query = DbContext.Table.Where(x => x.z == true).Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });
foreach(var item in query)
{
    // Do the work
}
```

I end up with this anonymous type and everything is fine. Now something comes up that makes me condition the Where clause, so I have to make a different query according to the condition and this is where I'm really frustrated:

```
if(something)
{
    var query = DbContext.Table.Where(x => x.z == true && x.zz == false).Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });
    foreach(var item in query)
    {
        // Do the work
    }
}
else
{
    var query = DbContext.Table.Where(x => x.z == true).Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });
    foreach(var item in query)
    {
        // Do the work
    }
}
```

because the work to be done in the `foreach` cycle is exactly the same and I shouldn't have to repeat it.

So, instead of working with the anonymous type I declared a new class and tried this:

```
class MyQuery
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public decimal? c { get; set; }
}

IQueryable<MyQuery> query = null;

if(something)
{
    query = (IQueryable<MyQuery>)DbContext.Table.Where(x => x.z == true && x.zz == false).Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });
}
else
{
    query = (IQueryable<MyQuery>)DbContext.Table.Where(x => x.z == true).Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });
}

foreach(var item in query)
{
    // Do the work
}
```

But now I have an `'System.InvalidCastException'` thrown because I'm still getting an anonymous type and apparently it can't be casted into my class.

I want to avoid the repetition of code for the sake of maintenance but I don't know how to do it. I feel that I'm missing something basic here but can't find what so your help is welcome and appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're second code would still work with the anonymous class (just remove the cast).  The only time you'd need a custom class is when you want to pass the data into or out of a method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it:

```
IQueryable<MyQuery> query = DbContext.Table;

if (something)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.z == true && x.zz == false)
}
else
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.z == true);
}

var result = query.Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });

foreach (var item in result)
{
    // Do the work
}
```

The `.Where()` method doesn't change the "type" of the query!

Note even that this is legal:

```
var query = DbContext.Table.Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });

if (something)
{
    query = DbContext.Table.Where(x => x.z == true && x.zz == false).Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });
}
else
{
    query = DbContext.Table.Where(x => x.z == true).Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });
}

foreach (var item in query)
{
    // Do the work
}
```

I'm using the fact that anonymous types with the same parameters (same name of the parameters, same type of parameters, same number of parameters) inside the same assembly are "unified" by the C# compiler. I use this line `var query = DbContext.Table.Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });` only to "give" the type to the `var` variable. Then I overwrite completely the query with other queries, because the various `.Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });` "produce" objects of the same (anonymous) type.

Comment: Yes I was overcomplicating. It was the something basic that I was missing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the `Where` condition to match a case or another. This way you no longer need to worry about duplicate code or creating another class that will be used only on this method.

```
var query = DbContext.Table.Where(x => something && (x.z == true && x.zz == false) || !something && (x.z == true)).Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });
foreach(var item in query)
{
    // Do the work
}
```

Or you can add a *ternary comparison* how @Rawling mentioned.

```
var query = DbContext.Table.Where(x => something ? (x.z == true && x.zz == false) : (x.z == true)).Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, x.c });
foreach(var item in query)
{
    // Do the work
}
```

Comment: @adricar Note that sometimes the query compiler/optimizer of the SQL could be "derailed" by having "dead" pieces of `where`...

Comment: I feel `x => something ? (x.z == true && x.zz == false) : (x.z == true)` is clearer here.

Comment: @Rawling you are a genius :D, this look more better